# How to disable specific warning during Maven execution?

Tags: maven

Due to the configuration I'm using, I get lots of these:

```
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for local-deps:[...] should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/[...] will be unresolvable by dependent projects [...]
```

Since this is how the application is currently setup, I can't fix them; but they clutter the console, so is there a way to disable them? `mvn --quiet` is not an option because it removes too many messages.

Comment: Never should you hide warning messages. They are warnings for a _good reason_. On another note, `mvn -q` is the only way to go so if it is not an option, there's really nothing you can do.

Comment: @Tunaki I know man ;-) but as I said, there's no way to fix them given the current situation. Thank you, I thought I missed something when I searched on the topic.

Comment: @watery Don't you have a Nexus instance where you can deploy your dependencies?

Comment: @Michael-O Not yet. It's one of my objectives, I just hadn't had the chance so far.

Comment: @watery That is the best to solve the problem because `system` scope will go away.

Comment: I am more interested in solving the underlying problem. Is Nexus the first-party way to solve this problem?

Comment: The best option I see is to move to Gradle, if you can. In Gradle adding local files is totally easy

Answer (score 2):

See the [Maven 3.1.x logging](https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html) documentation. You can configure the log level by editing the `${M2_HOME}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties` file. First set the value of `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName` to `true` and you will see the logname that prints your unwanted message. After that add the line `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.a.b.c=error` where `a.b.c` is the logname.

Comment: It turns out to be `org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven`, I feel I could suppress other important warnings this way. I mean, it's not selective enough for me. Anyway, this is a good suggestion.

Comment: I think thre is no deeper level of customization.