# How to solve Maven Invoker API warning: Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-invoker-plugin

I have a plugin which invokes Maven runs using MavenInvokerAPI. Everything is working fine, but I do have this warning in my Maven console output.

```
[WARN] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
```

I do not need interaction in my build process, and based on Javadoc of `setInputStream()`, I set my `inputStream` to `null`, but again I have this warning:

```
   /**
     * Sets the input stream used to provide input for the invoked Maven build. This is in particular useful when
     * invoking Maven in interactive mode.
     * 
     * @param inputStream The input stream used to provide input for the invoked Maven build, may be <code>null</code>
     *            if not required.
     * @return This invoker instance.
     */
    Invoker setInputStream( InputStream inputStream );
```

How can I solve this? Or maybe hide the warning from console?

Comment: This other question may help if you want to hide the warning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782089/how-to-change-maven-logging-level-to-display-only-warning-and-errors   or   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682374/how-to-disable-specific-warning-during-maven-execution

Comment: does not solve the problem, because even using -q I have the warnings

Answer (score 4):

Just set an empty InputStream

```
InvocationRequest invocationRequest = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
invocationRequest.setInputStream(InputStream.nullInputStream());
...
```